# Constant values in Fortran

Tags: input, fortran

I have an input file to read values from and one such value is `1d10`.

How to make sense of that value?

The input file is below and its for LU factorization:

```
8000   8000    8000    1d10               120  120    8
```

The variables above are:

```
min_n   max_n    stepsize  total_flops_in_timing_block   blower  bupper  bstride
```

Comment: Did not understand your question.

Comment: can you post a few lines of your input file that show its format?

Comment: Fortran uses `D` instead of `E` for double precision, so that number could be 10000000000. But we can't say without knowing the context of your file.

Comment: added the input file.

Comment: `d` is interpreted es `e`. Some compilers allow `q` as an extension, it also just interpreted es `e`. There is no "precision" to be cared about when interpreting input data.

Comment: What do you mean with "How to make sense of that value?"

Comment: I voted to reopen this question -- as casey's answer makes clear the question is clear enough to elicit a good answer from someone knowledgable in the field, and it is definitely programming related.  Arguably it's better than many other open questions here on SO too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I wanted to know what that 1d10 mean, looks like its a way of telling Fortran that its 1^10.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming all of those values are integers except for the flops variable, this example code will work.  Also note this depends on the fixed width of your input file and the values being separated by a single space.  If you have more general needs this will need tweaking to work.

```
program test
implicit none
  integer :: n_min, n_max, n_step, b_low, b_high, b_stride
  integer :: ufile
  real(kind=kind(1d0)) :: flops
  open(newunit=ufile, file="input2.txt", access="sequential")
  read(ufile,*) n_min, n_max, n_step, flops, b_low, b_high, b_stride
  close(ufile)
  print *, "min_n = ", n_min
  print *, "max_n = ", n_max
  print *, "stepsize = ", n_step  
  print *, "flops = ", flops
  print *, "blower = ",b_low
  print *, "bupper = ", b_high
  print *, "bstride = ", b_stride
end program test
```

Given the input file:

```
8000 8000 8000 1d10 120 120 8
```

produces this output:

```
% ./read_input 
 min_n =         8000
 max_n =         8000
 stepsize =         8000
 flops =    10000000000.000000     
 blower =          120
 bupper =          120
 bstride =            8
```

Comment: For my money the formatted read is not only unnecessary, it makes the read statement 'fragile' in the sense that success depends on a precise match between the format and the layout of the file.  A few extra spaces here or there and it will break.  `read(ufile,*)` is simpler and likely to be more robust.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark thanks for the comment.  I have edited to reflect the much easier and more robust approach.  As you can probably tell, I don't often use raw Fortran read/write IO and instead opt for formats like hdf5 and netcdf but do use the occasional namelist.